# Rails5: Todo Lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using as base [this project](https://github.com/zeitchef/todo) to work with todo lists. In this project, we can create multiple todo lists, click on them and open a specific todo list to see or check items.

What I want is at the index.html.erb when the todo lists are listed, the items of each one also be listed with the todo lists, so I can have the checklists and they items at the same place on index.html.erb. Someone know which is the best practice todo that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the relationship is set up in the model you can use that to accomplish this.

```
<% @todo_lists.each do |todo_list| %>
  <div class="index_row clearfix">
    <h2 class="todo_list_title"><%= link_to todo_list.title, todo_list %></h2>
    <p class="todo_list_sub_title"><%= todo_list.description %></p>
  </div>
  <% if todo_list.todo_items.any? %> # This will use the relationship set up to find any items belonging to this todo list
    <% todo_list.todo_items.each do | item | %> # Loop through the todo items for this list
       # code goes in here for the item, whatever you are thinking
       <p><%= item.content %></p> # or whatever you may need for the item
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It works. But how can I add the render <%= render todo_list.todo_items, todo_list %> to add items to each list?